# EventListeners not getting callback while using Inappbrowser in my ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, hybrid

I am using ionic,i need to open an external link in inappbrowser.After opening the external link,the new window gets detached from the app and Eventlisteners are not getting callback.I also tried window.open() instead of cordovaInappbrowser.open(),stil not recieving callback for eventlisteners.Also tried Iframe,still the same result.I am using ionic 1.3.0

```
 ref = window.open('#/pay', "_blank", 'location=no,hidden=yes');


                ref.addEventListener("loadstart", function(event){
                    console.log('load',event.url);

                },true);
                ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(event){

                    alert(event.url);

                });
                ref.addEventListener("loaderror", function(){

                    ref.close();
                });
```

Comment: hmm. Strange. I have no problem using this. What ionic version are you on? you can't possible have 1.7.14 as you write as 1.3.1 is the most recent. And what version of the inappbrowser? I've see people complaining that events are not firering when location=no, try change to location=yes.

Comment: sorry,ionic version is 1.3.0 and inappbrowser is 1.4.0.I did tried changing location no to yes, still same result.

Comment: Try updating to newest ionic. Also did you remember to wrap in 'device ready' call? what device are you testing on? did you try other devices?

Comment: also try removing and readding the plugin.

Comment: none of these worked

Answer (score 1):

Is that link `#/pay` opening fine inside inAppBrowser?  There is no hostname before it.
You can also check, it is not going to error callback function.
try adding `ref.addEventListener("loaderror", function(event){alert(event.message);` ...
to get the error details.